How to find out if an Android device supports hardware backed keystore
So far all the examples I have found on the Internet that check if a key is stored in hardware backed AndroidKeyStore do need to create the key first and then extract KeyInfo out of the key to check if the key is secured by hardware.
For my application, one of the requirements is that the keyPair is stored in hardware backed keyStore. Another requirement is to use ECDH when possible. However I find that many devices don't support hardware backed storage of Agreement keys, but they do support RSA keyPairs hardware backed storage.
I need to implement a fallback mechanism and I was wondering if there's a way of checking this without having to create keys.
